# What Is The Most Reliable Source For Getting Real Time Exchange Rates?

Tags: currency, foreign-exchange

What is the most reliable and up-to-date source for getting world currency exchange rates?

Comment: "the most reliable"? is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/finance/currencies) to be THE source.

Answer (score 1):

[XE](http://www.xe.com/) and [Oanda](http://www.oanda.com/) would be one of your safe bets. And it is in real time too. But a strict no no for using their services. They give very low exchange rates.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one](http://www.forexdirectory.net/quotesfx.html) that appears to be real time.

If you're wanting to trade, you'll likely get something better than this with your forex trading account.

Answer (score 0):

Forex rates are universal. Most of the website provide you with almost the same exchange rates with a margin of +/- 5 pips which is usually due to different spreads provided by different institutions or server delay.

Check out:

www.netdania.com
www.xe.com
www.fxstreet.com
www.dailyfx.com

I personally use netdania's application on my iPhone